# How to properly use $group operator in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I am currently struggling with the MongoDB query in which I want to group data by 2 fields `myId` and `myType`, but the results that I get in return don't look like what I need.
My goal is to have for each `myId` results with `myType` grouping. Like:

```
myId : {myType1 : 5, myType2 : 3, myType3 : 1}
```

But when I am trying to provide query with group operator like below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
"$project": {
  "myId": "$myId",
  "myType": "$eventType",
  }
},
{
   "$group":{
      "_id":{
         "myId":"$myId",
         "myType":"$Type"
      },
      "count":{
         "$sum":1
      }
   }
}
])
```

Results returned by this kind of grouping looks like this

```
[{'_id': {'myId': 'qwerty123', 'myType': 'created', 'count': 1}}, 
{'_id': {'myId': qwerty123', 'myType': 'removed', 'count': 3}},
{'_id': {'myId': qwerty123', 'myType': 'updated', 'count': 2}},
{'_id': {'myId': 'asd123', 'myType': 'created', 'count': 1}}, 
{'_id': {'myId': asd123', 'myType': 'removed', 'count': 2}}]
```

But what I would like to achieve is a structure like below:

```
[{'_id': {'myId': 'qwerty123', 'myType': {'created' 1, 'removed' : 3, 'updated' : 2}}},
{'_id': {'myId': 'asd123', 'myType': {'created' 1, 'removed' : 2}}}]
```

Or maybe like this:

```
[{'qwerty123', 'myType': {'created' 1, 'removed' : 3, 'updated' : 2}},
{'asd123', 'myType': {'created' 1, 'removed' : 2}}]
```

Is it possible to achieve results from `$group` operator with the above schema? If yes, how can I achieve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below stage after your above one

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
        _id: "$_id.myId",
        myType: {
            $push: {
                $arrayToObject: [
                    [
                        {
                            k: "$_id.myType",
                            v: "$_id.count"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            } 
        }
    }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GmAixf9cHxC)